# Is the project.properties file of my Android project still used?

Tags: android, android-build

I use the new Gradle-based build system.

I see project.properties has `target=android-19` and I see AndroidManifest.xml also has:

```
<uses-sdk ... android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
```

Then there are the dependencies, for example `android.library.reference.1=barone` and I see build.gradle also has these:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':barone')
```

Answer (score 0):

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide mentions "the project.properties file of the old build system" so it does not seem to be used anymore.